# If $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $q > 3$, does it follow that ${q^k}\sigma(q^k) \equiv q\sigma(q) \equiv 2 \pmod {q - 1}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $q > 3$ (where $q$ is prime), does it follow that ${q^k}\sigma(q^k) \equiv q\sigma(q) \equiv 2 \pmod {q - 1}$?

Observe that $q\sigma(q) \mid {q^k}\sigma(q^k)$ when $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

I got $q\sigma(q) \equiv 2 \pmod {q - 1}$ (for $q > 3$) from this [Wolfram link](http://functions.wolfram.com/NumberTheoryFunctions/DivisorSigma/32/01/).

Edit:  After taking to anon, I would like to add that, for the problem I am considering, I actually have $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  anon's answer gave $k \equiv 1 \pmod {q - 1}$ as a condition to check for the validity of the conjecture above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $q$ is prime, we can use the fact that 
$$q\equiv (q-1)+1\equiv 1\mod (q-1)$$

in order to obtain the slightly more general result (for *any* nonnegative integers $r,k\ge0$)

$$\begin{array}{c l} q^r\sigma_1(q^k) & =q^r\big(q^0+q^1+q^2+\cdots+q^k\big) \\[3pt] & \equiv (1)^r(\underbrace{1+1+1+\cdots+1}_{k+1}) \\ & \equiv k+1 \mod (q-1).\end{array}$$

Of course plugging in $k=1$ and $r=1$ gives $q\,\sigma_1(q)\equiv 2\mod (q-1)$ as in the Wolfram link. The only reason the link says $q\ne3$ is because then the symbol '$2$' actually means $0$ modulo $3-1=2$.

(This means the conjecture is not generally true unless $k\equiv1\bmod (q-1)$ happens to hold.)

Comment: So the conjecture is false for $k=5$ and big $q$, then?

Comment: @EricStucky Yes. Try [$q=7$ and $r=k=5$ for instance](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E5+DivisorSigma%5B1%2C7%5E5%5D+modulo+6).

Comment: You should probably put that in the answer :)

Comment: @anon: What if, for the prime $q$, it is also true that $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?  It will follow that $k \equiv 1 \pmod {q - 1}$, doesn't it?

Comment: @ArnieDris I don't follow. The integer $k$ can be chosen completely independently of $q$, right?

Comment: @anon, for the problem I'm considering, I actually have $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  But in principle, yes - the integer $k$ can be chosen (albeit, not completely) independently of $q$.

Comment: I get it now.  It doesn't necessarily follow from $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ that $k \equiv 1 \pmod {q - 1}$.  $k \equiv 1 \pmod {q - 1}$ means that $(q - 1) \mid (k - 1)$, while $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies only that $\gcd(q - 1, k - 1) \geq 4$.

Comment: @ArnieDris Yes that's correct.

Comment: @anon, before I accept your answer, can you please plug in additional details for the case when $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?  I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @ArnieDris I'm not sure that case entails any additional details. On the hypothesis that $q\equiv k\equiv1\bmod 4$, the conjecture (ie residue $\equiv2$) holds if and only if $\displaystyle\frac{q-1}{4}\mid\frac{k-1}{4}$ (which is a way to rewrite $k\equiv1\bmod (q-1)$), and I don't think anything further can be said because $(k-1)/4$ and $(q-1)/4$ have no further conditions on them. (Also if you get a message about "extended discussion" and chat, ignore it.)

Comment: @anon, I think that divisibility constraint should be $\displaystyle\frac{q-1}{4}\mid\displaystyle\frac{k-1}{4}$. Anyway, yes - I agree that nothing further can be said about $\displaystyle\frac{q-1}{4}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{k-1}{4}$ without additional information about $q$ and $k$.  Thanks for your help!  :)